# where can I find matrix like chart for ios frameworks

Tags: ios

Is there any website similar to http://iossupportmatrix.com/ where I can find the matrix of ios frameworks and compatibility. Basically if I want to use some of the framework feature I would like to refer to the matrix and see if the compatibility across os versions.

Comment: Lookup the class/method in the docs and see when it was added (and deprecated). Then you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple maintains this list in their website below is the link to apple website for feature change from ios 6 till date

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008246